How to make stepper function increment by fraction of a number every step in Javascript?
I have this function, but it gives me random values like 0.35000000000000003 every now and then:
function roundToFractionOfPercent(
  value: number,
  step: number,
): number {
  return Math.round(value / step) * step
}

You call it like this (in theory):
roundToFractionOfPercent(0.0163, 0.01) // => 0.02

How can you take a value which can be up to however many decimal places JS supports (6-8 is plenty), and have it increment by a random stepping value from as small as 0.00000001 to as large as 1, and anything in between like 0.0007 or 0.04 (increment by that amount).
Basically I am implementing a custom stepper input outside of HTML, and need to know how to handle it on decimal values.


Does this answer your question? How to round float numbers in javascript?

The issue you're encountering with floating-point rounding errors is common in JavaScript due to the way numbers are represented internally. Here's an improved version of your function,
Improved Function
function roundToFractionOfPercent(value, step) {
  const multiplier = 1 / step; // Avoid division later
  return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

Handling Very Small Steps:
If you're dealing with extremely small steps (like 0.00000001), consider this approach:Temporarily multiply both the value and the step by a large enough number to avoid floating-point issues during the calculation. For example:
function roundToFractionOfPercent(value, step) {
    const scalingFactor = 1e10; // 10 to the power of 10
    const scaledValue = value * scalingFactor;
    const scaledStep = step * scalingFactor;
    return Math.round(scaledValue / scaledStep) * scaledStep / scalingFactor;
}

